# How to extract particular ownText JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
String linkText = link.text(); // "example""

String linkOuterH = link.outerHtml(); 
    // "<a href="http://example.com"><b>example</b></a>"
String linkInnerH = link.html(); // "<b>example</b>"
```

In this example i want to just extract "An","link" so on. For example I want to get the text before the node  ie "An" and after the node ie "link." in the above example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the text of the paragraph, select it and ask for its own text:

```
Element p = doc.select("p").first();
System.out.println(p.ownText());
```

if you want the parts that construct that text, you can traverse the child nodes of that element and select only those that are TextNode instances:

```
for (Node node :p.childNodes()){
    if (node instanceof TextNode){
        System.out.println(((TextNode)node).text()); 
    }
}
```